# Is there a way to get a list of all asset pairs being traded on the distributed exchange, and the order book for each?

Tags: dex

For example, I see a few here:
https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/stellar-decentralized-exchange/

Are there more, and if so what's the data source?

Thank you.

Comment: i.e. Where are all of the "sheep and wheat"? https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/exchange.html#orderbook

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An asset on the stellar network is defined by its asset code (max 12 characters long code) and issuer. [For example](https://stellar.expert/explorer/asset/CNY-GAREELUB43IRHWEASCFBLKHURCGMHE5IF6XSE7EXDLACYHGRHM43RFOX) CNY and Ripplefox (GAREELUB43IRHWEASCFBLKHURCGMHE5IF6XSE7EXDLACYHGRHM43RFOX).

If you have access to a stellar-core instance database, the orderbook is contained in the `offers` table of the `score` database. The table schema is the following:

```
                Table "public.offers"
      Column      |         Type          | Modifiers 
------------------+-----------------------+-----------
 sellerid         | character varying(56) | not null
 offerid          | bigint                | not null
 sellingassettype | integer               | not null
 sellingassetcode | character varying(12) | 
 sellingissuer    | character varying(56) | 
 buyingassettype  | integer               | not null
 buyingassetcode  | character varying(12) | 
 buyingissuer     | character varying(56) | 
 amount           | bigint                | not null
 pricen           | integer               | not null
 priced           | integer               | not null
 price            | double precision      | not null
 flags            | integer               | not null
 lastmodified     | integer               | not null
```

To get a list of all unique asset pair, we run the following sql query:

```
select distinct sellingassettype, sellingassetcode, sellingissuer,
       buyingassettype, buyingassetcode, buyingissuer
from offers;
```

Which returns around 216 assets pairs.

While the columns assetcode and issuer are self-explanatory, assettype may need some explanation. At the low-level stellar has 3 assets: Native, and 2 for Credit assets (one with code of maximum 4 characters, another with maximum 12). In the database, `assettype = 0` is the native assets (Lumens), 1 is the 4 char code asset, and 2 is the 12 char code asset.

From the same table, you can extract the orderbook data you need for each individual asset.

Comment: It should be noted that this requires access to the internal database of a stellar-core node instance.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with the other answer - looking into internal database is the easiest and most comprehensive way.

But if you don't run your own node, then you could just query horizon:

https://horizon.stellar.org/assets?limit=100&cursor=0

and then request `orderbook` for each pair you're interested in

Comment: This is great, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[StellarTerm](https://stellarterm.com) maintains and uses a list of pairs in the stellarterm directory [here](https://github.com/irisli/stellarterm/blob/master/directory/directory.json#L610).

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good list here on [StellarExpert](https://stellar.expert/explorer/asset).

Comment: Nice, thanks. Do you know the specific data source via Stellar?